# Empty and Default costructor are same or different?

Tags: c++

The constructor with  no arguments is declared. Can it be treated as a default constructor? and if the constructor with no arguments has no statements inside will it be a default or empty constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should distinguish between terms *default constructor* and *explicitly defaulted constructor*. According to the C++ Standard (12.1 Constructors)

> 4 A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that
>   can be called without an argument.

From this definition for example it follows that in general case default constructor may have parameters. Moreover the same constructor can be a default constructor and non-default constructor.

Consider the following example

Let's assume that you defined a class with a constructor with one parameter

```
struct A
{
    A( int );
};
```

Till now it is not a default construtor. You may not write for example

```
A a1;
```

the compiler will issue an error. But you may write

```
A a1( 10 );
```

Then after this definition of a1 there is definition of the constructor with a default argument

```
A::A( int = 0 ) {}
```

Now the constructor has become a default constructor and you may write

```
A a2;
```

The whole example will look like

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A( int );
};

//A a1; - compilation error
A a1( 10 );

A::A( int = 0 ) {}

A a2; // O'k

int main() 
{

    return 0;
}
```

The explicitly defaulted constructor is a constructor that defined with keyword **default**. Explicitly defaulted constructor may not have default arguments.
Here is an example of a default constructor that is explicitly defaulted

```
struct A
{
    A() = default;
};
```

So a default constructor that was defaulted may not have parameters.

As for this your question

> if the constructor with no arguments has no statements inside will it
>   be a default or empty constructor?

then there is no such a term as empty constructor in the C++ Standard. However the defaulted default constructor looks the same way as a user defined default constructor with an empty body. From the C++ Standard (12.1 Constructors, paragraph #5)

> The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of
>   initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written
>   default constructor for that class with no ctor-initializer (12.6.2)
>   and an empty compound-statement.

Take into account that there is a great difference between implicitly defined by the compiler and explicitly user-defined with empty body copy constructors. I described it
[here](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-1-20-00000021-000-0-0-1388485669) Though it is written in Russian but I think you can translate in English using browser  or web (for example google) service translate.

Answer (score 4):

From C++11 standard N3376 12.1/5

> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that
>   can be called without an argument. If there is no user-declared
>   constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is
>   implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4)

So constructor without arguments (declared, or not declared) is default constructor.

Comment: C++ compilers generates an implicit default constructor if you do not explicitly define one. However, with C++ 11, you can also prevent this implicitly generated default constructor. Please, have a look the section " Deleted implicitly-declared default constructor" on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor.

Comment: @Deniz Yes, I know, that default constructor can be defined as deleted, however, it have no relation to question.

Comment: Extra information does not hurt anyone, I think (especially when C++11 was mentioned).

Answer (score 3):

Yes because a default constructor is one that can be called without arguments.

Comment: The question is: *Empty and Default costructor are same or different?* What does **"Yes"** mean in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

In reference to standard c++

```
yes it will be default constructor.
constructor with no arguments will be treated as default constructor.
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be said that a default constructor is a constructor with no parameters or all parameters have default arguments. For more info, please look at [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor) . Both of them is acceptable as a default argument. In addition to that, a default constructor can be explicitly or implicitly defined. If you do not explicitly define one, compiler generates an implicit default constructor for you. There is an exception for C++11 (please see my comment for the answer of @ForEver), which is a new ans usable feature instead of private (copy) constructors for some patterns I think.

I do not know a term like "Empty Constructor", because C++ compilers do not interested in what you have done inside the constructor. They only (implicitly) define and/or execute it. So you are free to do whatever you want (of course without causing a crash and etc.) inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When an object is created without any parameters, it calls default constructor. Generally it is a constructor without argument, but not always.

```
class FOO 
{
    int i;  
public:   
    FOO(int iVal = 10) 
    {
        i = iVal;   
    }
};
```

In above case the constructor with default parameter is a default constructor.

Empty Constructor is nothing. May be you are trying to ensure that no member variables are initialized.